# How can I manipulate socket.io data, perhaps via proxy, or as a middleware?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I've been searching Google and SO for a couple of weeks now to solve this one problem that has been pestering me. I will first outline what my objective is, then I will try to explain how close I've come to solving it.

### Objective:

To inject a small `express` server in between a large application, and its data-api, for the sole purpose of manipulating data responses from the server (or curating custom responses in place of the ones the server responded with).

We are using `socket.io` to connect the client with the server, and there are actually precious few events I actually want to modify. Most of the events I want to proxy back and forth between the client and the server unmodified.

However there are those precious few events that I want custom responses to be sent back to the client for testing purposes

### What I've tried:

I've tried to make a basic express server both a `socket.io-client` and a `socket.io` server. I don't know how to proxy my requests through to each other though, and am especially wary about the possibility of tracking multiple clients. Linking here is the key, and I'm stumped

I've also tried using [http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) which has gotten me pretty close, however the only thing thus far I have been able to do is to inspect payloads as they come and go using `socket.on('data', (data) => { /* do something */ });` inside of my `proxy.on('open', socket => {});` event.

So while I can see tons of data coming and going, I still need the chance to manipulate it.

Is this something anyone has done before? Is there a good resource out there about how to make an express server act as a proxy by connecting client connections to the server?

Thanks in advance for your expertise. I fear this may be a bit too advanced.

Comment: FYI for anyone coming upon this, I think I ended up coming with my own solution. I have something wired up, but it involved me writing test cases for each event, which I didn't want to have to do. However it works, which was my main concern. If I execute on my vision to have a true proxy, with only a few explicit catches, I promise I'll post my answer here as a follow-up

Answer (score 0):

Ok as I promised I came up with half of my ideal solution. Ideally I want to proxy *all* events back & forth and only listen to a few key events, but I haven't figured that part out yet. If anyone can assist me in that endeavor I'd be forever grateful.

Instead, I just map out all of the events that each end of the socket emits and bury them within the connected calls.

Here's the nuts and bolts about how I did what I wanted - you create a `server` as normal, and on its connection, you then initiate a `client` connection from within the `.on('connection', () => {});` call. Once within this scope, you can be relatively sure that both connections are open, and start passing events back and forth. Ideally you'd be checking for an active connection but if your server and/or client are equipped to handle a severed connection, you are probably ok.

You'll see in my simple example below how I pass events back and forth, and it gets the job done. Like I said if anyone can help me out with a wildcard like approach (which I couldn't get working for some reason) please let me know!

```js
// GLOBAL CONFIGS
const serverConfig = {}; // Feel free to add your desired options here

// Some of these options pertain more to me than they will to you; don't feel like
// you have to copy these configs
const clientConfig = {
  // We don't want to pre-emptivly try to connect to data-api,
  // because we need our client to give us data first.
  autoConnect: false,
  multiplex: false,
  // Disables/bypasses long polling which causes the connection to
  // be severed then re-connected (for my api at least)
  transports: ["websocket"]
};

const PORT = 3000;
const PROXY_HOST = '<api-endpoint-goes-here>'
const NAMESPACE = '<the name of your namespace, if applicable>';

// SERVER STUFF - this will connect to your client
const app = require('express')();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const cors = require('cors');
const io = require('socket.io')(server, serverConfig);
const nsp = io.of(`/${NAMESPACE}`);

// CLIENT STUFF - this will connect to your api server as a client
const client = require('socket.io-client');
const ioClient = client(`${PROXY_HOST}/${NAMESPACE}`, clientConfig);

// Self explanatory I hope
app.use(cors());

// I am going to call this a root socket - meaning no namespace. Not entirely useful for now unless
// we want to inspect transitions in and out of our namespace, but just putting it here FYI
io.on('connection', socket => {
  console.log(`A connection to the root socket made ${socket.handshake.headers.origin}`);

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log(`A client disconnected from the root socket.`);
  });
});

// Serve up a basic html file so that we can interact with our socket.io instance in the
// console. This index.html has a similar setup with a socket connection to both the data
// api and this test server, so I can ping events via console and test how this is working
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});

// Run the server
server.listen(PORT, () => console.log('Test data server is running'));

// Here's where the real solution reveals itself for me :)

// Listen for connections to the namespace we are looking for - this is the meat & potatoes of our app
nsp.on('connection', socket => {
  console.log(`the ${NAMESPACE} namespace was connected`);

  // Time to initiate a connection to the ioClient because we need it for the app now
  ioClient.connect();

  // Now check to make sure ioCLient is connected. Once we get inside here, we can be 
  // reasonably sure that we have a connection to both the client, and the data-api
  ioClient.on('connect', () => {
    // Acknowledge we have connected to the data-api
    console.log('Connected to data-api via socket.io');

    // Events sent from data-api
    ioClient.on('<your event>', data => {
      socket.emit('<your event>', data);
    });

    ioClient.on('<your event with two params>', (data1, data2) => {
      socket.emit('<your event with two params>', data1, data2);
    });
    
    // ... etc

    // Other event catchers for ioClient
    ioClient.on('disconnect', () => {
      console.log('Disconnected from the data-api');
    });
    
    ioClient.on('error', err => {
      console.error('Error with the data-api connection: ', err);
    });

    // Events sent from the app client
    socket.on('<your event>', data => {
      ioClient.emit('<your event>', data);
    });

    socket.on('<your event with two params>', (data1, data2) => {
      ioClient.emit('<your event with two params>', data1, data2);
    });
    
    // ... etc
  });
});
```